# jquery datepicker date format "yy-mm-dd" on codeigniter

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have this jquery datepicker, and it works well but I want to format the date into `yy-mm-dd`, but the default is mm-dd-yy. Can someone help me this out?
here's my datepicker code:

```
<script> 
      var date = new Date();
      var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
      var currentDate = date.getDate();
      var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)

      });

</script>
```

my views

```
<div class="container" >
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <ul id="nav">
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'homepage'?>" title="Home"><h4>Home</h4></a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'news-and-events'?>" title="News and Events"><h4>News and Events</h4></a></li>
     <li><a href="" title="Activities"><h4>Activities</h4></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="starter-template">
      <h1>News And Events</h1>
      <form action="<?php echo base_url().'news-and-events/add'?>" method="post">
         <?php echo validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>');?>
        <table class="table-striped">
          <tr>
            <td>Date: </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" value="<?php echo set_value('date');?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td >Event: </td>
            <td ><input  type="text" name="event" value="<?php echo set_value('event');?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="20%">Description: </td>
            <td><textarea cols="30" rows="5" name="description" ><?php echo set_value('description');?></textarea></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
      <div style="float:left;">
        <input id="add_another" type="button" value="Add Another" class="btn btn-primary" />
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Event</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div><!-- /.container -->
```

I want that when I click on the date text box it formats to `yy-mm-dd`.
any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: From:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938734/jquery-ui-datepicker-output-date-format  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",` rest should be in the documentation of jquery datepicker

Comment: i tried to insert that code the dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" above the minDate and it wont work. i know that dateFormat code will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch the `datepicker` js-call, have you tried to define the `dateFormat` parameter?

Something like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

=> [jQuery dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

Maybe there is an error when you define the `minDate`. Try simply like this:

```
minDate: new Date() // today date
```

Comment: hi i tried that code that works the dateFormat but ahm my code above has the minDate and when i tried to insert that dateFormat above minDate wont work

Comment: @bobcatnyxz maybe there is an error when you define the minDate, try like I suggest in my edited answer

Comment: hey thanks anyways it now works what i judt did is put the comma after this satement  minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the picker as mentioned, make this change here:

```
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot men! it now works i didnt notice that it was a comma after this minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)